# Tableview cell only segues when I click where there are no elements Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So, I have a custom cell with 5 components on it. Two labels, two buttons, and a text view. I want to be able to segue from this cell to another screen. The segue has been set up, but when testing, I am only able to segue if you click on the cell in a place that isn't covered by an element. Since the text view is most of the cell, it is extremely hard to segue. How can I have it so if I click anywhere on the cell (besides the two buttons of course) it will segue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of your labels to `false`.
 Best do this in Interface Builder.

This will prevent the label from "stealing" the taps from your cell.